# NSDateFormatter get hour and time

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have string value with date(for ex.: **2012-11-30T12:45:00Z**), how can I get value like this: **12:45**? Thanks..

Comment: Well, you could just select characters 11 through 15 of the source string.  Or you could read the spec for NSDateFormatter, figure out how to read the string into an NSDate, then figure out how to write out the format you want.  But reading the spec would be the first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date formatter approach looks like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *hhmm = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];

// release dateFormatter if not using ARC... but use ARC
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString* timeStr = [longDateStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 5)];
```

Comment: This approach will work but anyone reading should keep in mind that it is not internationalized.

Comment: @AndreiStoleru What are your concerns?

Comment: @ilmiacs I think that using `substringWithRange` is bad practice, especially in cases like this where you have other options.